# Why this form submit isn't working as expected

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have this code in `test.php`.

- When I access the script just by typing it, I want to see just the form
- but when I click the form submit button, the next time the page loads, I want to see the form and some comment that says that the form has been submitted.

For some reason, even when I click submit, I don't get the message that it's posting. Anyone can explain why? and how can I get it to work.

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="inp" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />      
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "posting";
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: why action is empty? I recommend to use: if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'submit') {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a name to the input:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: this, you call $_POST using the name as keys

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo "posting";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="inp" />
<input type='hidden' name='submit' value=''>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />      
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "posting";
    }

    ?>
</body>
```