# How to display search details after search button is clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dom, button

I have a modal window where it contains a textbox and a search button. Now what I want is that when the user enters in a word and then clicks on the "Search" button, I want it to run the query and display the results wether there is a result or not.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the "Search" button to output the neccessary details after it has been cliked. At the moment if the user clicks on the "Search" button after typing in a word, nothing happens.

So I want just a normal function associated with the "Search" button so that it outputs the details after the search button has been clicked. How can this be achieved?

Here is a link to the [application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) so you can see what is happening.

Below is the full code:

```
<div class="previouslink">

<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return closewindow();">Close</button>
<h1>PREVIOUS QUESTIONS</h1>

<?php

      foreach (array('questioncontent') as $varname) {
        $questioncontent = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
      <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" value="<?php echo $questioncontent; ?>" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>

<?php

            if (isset($_POST['searchQuestion'])) {

              $questionquery = "SELECT QuestionContent FROM Question
          WHERE(QuestionContent = '".mysql_real_escape_string($questioncontent)."')";

      $questionnum = mysql_num_rows($questionresult = mysql_query($questionquery));
      ?>

     <p>
         Your Search: <?php echo "'$questioncontent'"; ?>
     </p>


      <?php
        if($questionnum ==0){
    echo "<p>Number of Questions Shown from the Search: <strong>$questionnum</strong></p>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, No Questions were found from this Search</p>";}
    else{
        echo"<p>Number of Questions Shown from the Search: <strong>$num</strong></p>";

      $output = "";
$output .= "
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      </tr>
";
        while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_array($questionresult)) {
$output .= "
      <tr>
      <td>{$questionrow['QuestionContent']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "        </table>";

        echo $output;

  }

  if (empty($questioncontent)){
    echo "Please enter in a phrase in the text box in able to search for a question";
}

}

  mysql_close();

?>

</div>
```

UPDATE BELOW:

```
<body>

                <?php

               if (isset($_POST['searchQuestion'])) {

                    echo "xxx";

                exit;

               }
?>

<form id="QandA" action="imageupload.php" method="post">

<h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS</h1>

<table id="plus" align="center">
<tr>
<th>
<a onclick="return plusbutton();">
<img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage"/>
</a>
<span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>
</th>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="previouslink">

<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return closewindow();">Close</button>
<h1>PREVIOUS QUESTIONS</h1>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
      <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>





</div>

</form> 

</body>
```

Comment: now try running your php if submit code on top of page baiscally its always on top not inside a calling form like i updated ur question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug what you are getting on clicking button search use exit see what your query is listing ,

when there is no form no action so nothing will happen on clicking search use proper code formatting

Comment: I have got no errors at all from error console and I have update the code but still no details being displayed. I am not just talking about rsults from a query, I am also talking about if it does not find a result, it is not displaying a message. I have included form tag and action method but still nothing

Comment: try exit; first just see if on clicking search  if you can get an hello world printed . i think problem is control is not passing have you used proper html tags form doesnt work without <html><head></head><bodyform is inside here </body></html>   no one will debug for you first check where is the control passing on submit

Comment: Well all html tags are in correct place. Can I ask you how to use the exit command? Is it php or a javascript command?

Comment: i get you are complete beginner .  its php used to debug till where is your control passing and what line you get an errror . at this line                                   if (isset($_POST['searchQuestion'])) { //add this code and see does this get printed  echo "xxx"; exit; }

Comment: if you look at bottom of question, I have mentioned UPDATE BELOW to show that I have tried your theory of echoing a string and exitting after search button is clicked. After search button is clicked it does not echo the string "xxx". Nothing is outputted. The updated code just shows the code in this [application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) so you can test it yourself as well :)

Comment: move the code to top of the page <?php

     if (isset($_POST['searchQuestion'])) { //add this code and see does this get printed echo "xxx"; exit; }

     echo "xxx";

     exit;

}

Comment: your problem is that your writing php code inside a form logic should be separate from presentation check this question how this is done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465745/why-this-form-submit-isnt-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

You should move your input tags inside a `<form method="POST"> </form>` block.

Comment: I hhave updated code and link to match your answer but it is still not displaying any details after search button has been clicked